# Using WCF NetTCPBinding Transport security mode, the channel cannot be opened between the client and the server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have one client machine and two server machines. The system of the server machine is the same.
**Server machine**
Windows Server 2019 Standard, Version:1809
.Net Framework 4.7 Advanced Service -> TCP Port Sharing open
**Client machine**
Windows 11 Pro, Version: 21H2
.Net Framework 4.8 Advanced Service -> TCP Port Sharing open
**The WCF client side code is as follows**
//Client side code:
NetTcpBinding bindings = new NetTcpBinding;
bindings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
bindings.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
string addr = "net.tcp://10.224.11.11:12345/MyTCPService";
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddresss(new Uri(addr), EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity(""));
ChannelFactory<MyTCPService.IDBAgent> myFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyTCPService.IDBAgent>(bindings, address);
MyTCPService.IDBAgent channel = myFactory.CreateChannel();
CommunicationState state = ((IClientChannel)channel).State;
if (state == CommunicationState.Created)
{
((IClientChannel)channel).Open();
}

```
//Server side code: 
string addr = "net.tcp://localhost:12345/MyTCPService";
ServiceHost serHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(DataAgent), new Uri(addr));
NetTcpBinding bindings = new NetTcpBinding;
bindings.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
bindings.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
bindings.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
bindings.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
bindings.TransactionFlow = false;
bindings.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
bindings.MaxBufferPoolSize = 1024;
bindings.MaxBufferSize = 1073741824;
bindings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1073741824;
bindings.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
bindings.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 64;
bindings.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
bindings.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
bindings.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
bindings.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
bindings.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:05:00");
bindings.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
bindings.ReliableSession.Enabled = false;
bindings.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttling = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
{
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 500,
    MaxConcurrentInstances = 500,
    MaxConcurrentSessions = 500
};

ServiceMetadataBehavior metadata = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
{
    HttpGetEnabled = false
};
serHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttling);
serHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadata);
serHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDBAgent), bindings, addr);
serHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBindings(), addr);
```

**Questions:**
The problem I encountered is that one of the two server machines cannot communicate with the client. I checked that the binding port and address are correct and the machine is in the same domain. I don't know what account Windows uses to establish communication. Is there any way to know? Why can't I open the channel? The socket connection was aborted when the client executed channel Open() function
Is there a way to obtain the certificate name of Windows authentication so that I can check whether the client and server of WCF match the certificate？
**What I do**
I checked that the binding port and address are correct and the machine is in the same domain. If I change Client to bindings Security Mode to None; Then you can connect to the server machine that failed to connect before, so I suspect that the Windows permissions of this machine have special settings, but I don't know where to find the settings.

Comment: Best way is to check event viewer on the remote machine for errors.  The client and two server should share a common password server to allow access between the machines.  Windows Authentication will go to password server to determine if a connection can be made.  The local and remote machines must use the same account to access the data.  Since you are using TCP I suspect that the Authentication is not Windows but OAUTH2.  It could also be using TLS encryption and you may need to update to Net 4.7.2 or later which has some fixes for TLS.  I do not know if Authentication or TLS is failing.

Comment: The two server machine are in the same domain with same user account and password, this WCF binding will use NNS encryption between client and server which will use Windows certificate. Besides, what information should I pay attention to in the Event Viewer?

Comment: At the time you are running the c# code.

Comment: Could you please share the specific error info? Also you could take a look at [authentication scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-multiple-authentication-schemes-with-wcf) in wcf and see if there are any differences compared to yours.

Comment: @Jiayao  The error message is: The socket connection was aborted. this could be caused by an error processing your message.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is : The socket connection was aborted. this could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue.

It was my fault. Now I find that the client is in the Win11 system and the server is in Windows Server 2019. In this case, using the above code, WCF connection will fail.
If Client and Server are on the same Windows version, then the connection will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that it was the problem of the login user I served. I used LOCAL SERVICE, so I did not have access rights.